# Integrating Admob in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am integrating AdMob into my android application.

I have followed the directions on the admob site to a T.In my attrs.xml I have the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
        <attr name="adSize">
            <enum name="BANNER" value="1" />
            <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2" />
            <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3" />
            <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="adUnitId" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And I setup the View in my main.xml

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               ads:adUnitId="MYID"
                               ads:adSize="BANNER" /
```

>

When viewing the main.xml in Graphical Layout it is giving an error on the AdView

```
Adview missing required XML Attribute "adSize"
```

Wondering if I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5) will help you.

Comment: Seems to help a little I get a new error.In the Graphical View of the xml. Parser is not a BridgeXmlBlockParser!
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on rochdev's answer:

There are some changes to the way Admob works in version 4.1.0. There's a [discussion on Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5) about this issue and how they haven't updated the documentation.

Google employee Tim posted:

> 1) Remove attrs.xml (or if you need it for your own custom attributes, remove the parts related to AdViews).
>
> 2) Change the namespace in your layout from `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.packagename"` to `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Once you have made those two changes, you should now see an ad.

If that doesn't fix it, try following the example [on this page](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389156) may be helpful.