# Not displaying google ads in Emulator or device

Tags: android-emulator

The code doesn't show any errors:

```
main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/googleads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="jkdfj8485idj34"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:refreshInterval="60"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="AD" />

</LinearLayout>

AdmobActivity.java
 AdView ad = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.googleads);

        ad.setEnabled(true);
        ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID);
        AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
        //r.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        r.addTestDevice("CD9E4FDFA47A4AA03F9883E77C036EB3");
        //r.setTesting(true);
        ad.loadAd(r);
```

I have the following warnings:

> 07-26 15:51:24.046: W/webcore(842): Can't get the viewWidth after the
>   first layout 07-26 15:51:24.871: W/Ads(842): Invalid unknown request
>   error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

See if these links help address the issue that you are facing:

- [How to get Google's example code working for AdMob 4.1.0 using an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389156/how-to-get-googles-example-code-working-for-admob-4-1-0-using-an-android-device)
- [android webview admob not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757849/android-webview-admob-not-displaying)